$\{a+b \mid \ a \in A, b \in B\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, prove that either $m(A) = 0$ or $m(B) = 0$.
Problem: Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with $\{a+b \mid \ a \in A, b \in B\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that either $m(A) = 0$ or $m(B) = 0$.
My effort: Assume they both have positive measure.
Let $A' = -A$ and we have $B\cap \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q} } q + A' = \emptyset$. Essentially, I want to say if $m(A) > 0$, then  $\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q} } q + A'$ will take up most of the space on the real line and the remaining part is of measure $0$. (B can only sits in the remaining part.)
I think what I can do is to assume that $A$ has finite measure by taking $A = A \cap[-N_1, N_1]$. Let $\{r_{n}\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Fix $\epsilon$, by regularity, we can find open set $U_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$ such that $U_n\supset A' + r_n$ and $m(U_{n}\setminus (A'+r_n)) < 2^{-n}\epsilon$. I want $\bigcup_{n} U_n = \mathbb{R}$ so that $B$ can only sit in each $U_{n}\setminus (A'+r_n)$, whose measure sums up to $\epsilon$ at most. As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we may conclude that $B = 0$.
Can anyone help me build the proof? Thanks!
